# LuaJit predefine struct

Tags: struct, lua, ffi, luajit

I'm trying to make some structs that are dependant on each other in Lua like so. But I'm having problems doing it. Is there anyway I can predefine Foo as an empty struct and define it afterwards?

Thanks.

```
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct {
        Foo* foo;
    } Bar;
]]

ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct {
        Bar* bar;
    } Foo;
]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem specific of LuaJIT and the FFI but how to declare interdependent data structures and functions in C.

C requires that a function has been defined before using it. For instance:

```
int foo() {
    bar();
}

int bar() {
    return 42;
}
```

To solve this issue is necessary to declare function `bar()` at the beginning of the file. The behavior of the function can be defined later.

```
int bar();

int foo() {
    bar();
}

int bar() {
    return 42;
}
```

Similarly, you need to declare `Foo` before using it in `Bar`. Also notice it's possible to put all the C definitions in the same block.

```
ffi.cdef[[
   typedef struct Foo Foo;

   typedef struct {
      Foo* Foo;
   } Bar;

   typedef struct {
      Bar* bar;
   } Foo;
]]
```